# Audit trail techniques

Tags: audit, audit-trail

My project is in ASP.NET MVC3, SQL Server 2008 and using Fluent NHibernate.

I now have a requirement to audit certain properties of a specific object. 
i.e. recording the old and new value of the properties changed on that object and also create and delete events on the object itself.

I think there can be several ways to approach this task - database triggers, INotifyPropertyChanged interface, or any NHibernate provided features?
Alternatively any open source libraries that will make my life simpler.

However, what i am not sure about is which path to choose. I mean this is a very vast area where I can go on exploring and still can't come to any conclusion.

It will be really helpful if I can get some guidance as to which option will be best considering my requirement and I can look into it more from there.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it's enterprise version of SQL Server, that has Change Data Capture (CDC) - which is a built in feature for auditing changes to data within the database.

Comment: not sure about that but I will check. thanks for responding.

Comment: Are you looking for specific coding techniques and paradigms, or more general suggestions of frameworks to use and where to look for more info?

Comment: more general suggestions on frameworks to use I guess, because my requirement is very concise. It is an audit trail on selected objects only. if I can narrow down the areas i have to explore that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit biased but...
Have you had a look at Envers? https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers